# How can I combine IF and CONCATENATE to add text to Excel

Tags: excel, if-statement, concatenation

I'm totally newbie in Excel and I need a simple thing to solve, I can't combine IF with Concatenate in Excel, thank you in advance.

I need result in F2 like I wrote in G2

[image: I need result in F2 like I wrote in G2]

Comment: A couple of thoughts.  What happens if you just type `=C2=“Sabre”` in that cell?  That should say TRUE or FALSE whether C2 does actually equal “Sabre.”  My most likely suspicion is that C2 does not exactly equal “Sabre” but rather, contains a trailing space or some other non-visible character.  Also, CONCATENATE() was recently (Excel 2019 I think?) replaced by the more reliable CONCAT() function, or you can simply it further by using the “&” concatenation operator.

Comment: Ok, I almost figured out what is the problem, but here appears another one Sabre cell is a result of a formula, and that's the reason I guess why F2 appears to be false, how can I solve it?

Comment: If the problem is that the content of cell C2 is not *actually* exactly "Sabre", then you have two choices.  Change the formula that populates C2 so that it correctly says exactly "Sabre", or change the formula in F2 so that the IF() function is checking C2 for exactly what is in cell C2.  Those are your only two options.